# Further explanations on YouTube API quota: eg. does `search?maxResults` add up?

Tags: request, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

So, i'm a bit confused how youtube API queries impact on quota. They all lay out on a "composition" aspec of requisitions:

The [Quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost#recommendations-link) show the cost of various resources.
For example `search.list = 100` and `videos.list = 1`.

One aspect of it is not clear to me though. How it calculates on a 'multi-results' single request?

| query | quota doubt |
| --- | --- |
| `/search?maxResults=10` | is it **one** `100` quota, or **ten** `100` <sub>(1000)</sub> quotas? |
| `/videos?id=A,B` | is it **one** quota, or **two** quotas? |
| `/video?part=A,B` | is this *adding* **two** quotas? (*each* video??) Since no `?part=` returns only `id` related data |
| `/...?fields=A,B(C)` | is `fields` query impacting the request quota anyhow? |

---

---

I first thought it was really straightforward: *1 **call**, 1 quota "package"*. And that seemed to be supported by this calculator's quote:

> If your application calls a method, such as `search.list`, that returns multiple pages of results, ***each request*** to retrieve an additional page of results incurs the estimated quota cost.

But while developing a simple video list, my daily quota blew up pretty damn fast. So not sure anymore.

Comment: AFAIK quota is on a per HTTP request basis. Your last quote about `search.list` just says that by making multiple HTTP requests using each time a different `pageToken` it counts as how many different HTTP requests you do (which is equivalent to the number of requests with different `pageToken`  you do here). Anyway you can monitor your quota usage from the Google Cloud website.

Comment: Yeah, but the quota monitor is not reliable. When my request got blocked, is was showing that had done less than half of 10 000 daily limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call the method in question you incure the quota cost

For example:

```
search.list 100
```

WHen you call search.list it costs 100 if you call it again to get the next page of results it will cost you another 100 points.

Ig we check this one where you are trying to get back two videos.

```
/videos?id=A,B
```

The same is true it will be a single request to the server so the quota cost will be one.

Fields does not effect it.  Its just the request you make.  Batching will also not save you from quota cost.  If you batch these requests you will be charged for each of the quests within the back.

[Intro to YouTube API and cost based quota for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHUGuw1Agnc)

A lot of this information is on the [Quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) page.

> The table below shows the **quota cost for calling each API method**. All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.

> - If your application calls a method, such as search.list, that returns multiple pages of results, **each request to retrieve an additional page of results incurs the estimated quota cost**.

Comment: As stated on last part (including the quota cost page's quote about "each request"), that was my first thought. But i did just a couple of search & videos request, and soon my quota had blow out.

So say i made about 20 searchs and 500 videos list: 20 * 100 + 500 = 2500 -> ¼ of daily limit. That made me think it had something to do with `?id=A,B,C...` pattern.